# How to remove the symbol "\" in a string?

Tags: regex, r

```
a <- "1  \"US\", 2 \"UK\", 3 \"GE\""
```

I hope to get the following results:
1 US
2 UK
3 GE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
> a <- c("1  \"US\"","2 \"UK\"","3 \"GE\"")
> gsub("\"", "", a)
[1] "1  US" "2 UK"  "3 GE"
```

**OR**

```
> a <- "1 \"US\", 2 \"UK\", 3 \"GE\""
> gsub("\"", "", a)
[1] "1 US, 2 UK, 3 GE"
> gsub("\"|,", "", a)
[1] "1 US 2 UK 3 GE"
```

`\"` are usually used to mean a double quotes.

Comment: what about in python? I have a str like \\u5717\\u3a46 it is in the form of unicode and I want to change it into Chinese characters, sth like u'\u5717\u3a46'.

Answer (score 2):

There are no slashes in your string (length 1 character vector).

```
> cat(a)
1  "US", 2 "UK", 3 "GE"
```

The slashes you see are to escape the double quotes which otherwise would close the string. Compare what it would look like if you were using single quotes to delimit a string (in which case a double quote would not close it):

```
> identical(a, '1  "US", 2 "UK", 3 "GE"')
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to remove the commas,

```
> gsub(",", "", a)
[1] "1  \"US\" 2 \"UK\" 3 \"GE\""
```

If you want to display it without having it printed as a delimited string and without escaping things in it, use `cat`. You can even do both.

```
> cat(gsub(",", "", a))
1  "US" 2 "UK" 3 "GE"
```